# how i can capture particular query or procedure's resource usage.in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, cpu-usage

how i can capture particular query or procedure's resource usage in MySQL?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix your SQL statement with the word `EXPLAIN` and MySQL shows you the execution plan for how will run your statement.  And, you can prefix it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (or just `ANALYZE` in some versions) and it will run the statement and tell you what it actually did -- its actual execution plan --, along with times.

*Don't `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` statements that change your tables unless you actually want them changed.*

There is also a slow query log for long running statements. You can read about that.

Comment: It is working for only tables.. what about stored procedure?